# PayPal sandbox API SSL error after TLS 1.2 upgrade errno 54

Tags: curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox, tls1.2

Not sure if this is the best place to ask, but after the TLS 1.2 upgrade PayPal made on June 30, 2017, I'm unable to use their sandbox NVP endpoint: `https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp`

The live API `https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp` works as expected:

```
~ % curl "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?user=whatever"
ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

I get a response body from the server.

But if I try the same request with the sandbox I get:

```
~ % curl "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?user=whatever"
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
```

I've tried several combinations of forcing TLS 1.2 and insecure connections but they don't make a difference. Here's a verbose output:

```
~ % curl --insecure --tlsv1.2 -v "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?user=whatever"
*   Trying 173.0.82.83...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.83) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES256-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
*  start date: Jan 14 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 14 23:59:59 2018 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Symantec Corporation; OU=Symantec Trust Network; CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /nvp?user=whatever HTTP/1.1
> Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.1
> Accept: */*
>
* OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
```

I'm on macOS and have tried upgrading OpenSSL and cURL with MacPorts, I get the same behaviour in php70-curl which is also up to date with OpenSSL 1.0.2l. Also same behaviour after quickly checking on a FreeBSD machine with OpenSSL 1.0.2k:

```
* SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 54
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 54
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: You can rule out OpenSSL with `openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -tls1_2 -servername api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com`. `-tls1` fails, while `-tls1_2` succeeds. cURL also told you the problem was elsewhere when it reported *"TLS handshake, Finished"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by using POST instead of GET as noted in https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/merchant-security-roadmap
and https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/discontinuation-get-method

Also had to pass my POST data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`